# MDCBottomNavigationBar switch view

Tags: ios, swift, view, material-design, uitabbar

Не могу понять как в Material design iOS менять экран при нажатии на кнопки таб бара.

```
 func setup_TabBar(){
    colorScheme.backgroundColor = .white
    view.backgroundColor = colorScheme.backgroundColor


    let tabBarItem1 = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "Home"), tag: 0)
    let tabBarItem2 = UITabBarItem(title: "Trend", image: UIImage(named: "Disc"), tag: 1)
    let tabBarItem3 = UITabBarItem(title: "Subscribe", image: UIImage(named: "Sub"), tag: 2)
    let tabBarItem4 = UITabBarItem(title: "User", image: UIImage(named: "User"), tag: 3)

    bottomNavBar.items = [ tabBarItem1, tabBarItem2 , tabBarItem3 , tabBarItem4]
    bottomNavBar.selectedItem = tabBarItem1
    bottomNavBar.backgroundColor = .white
    view.addSubview(bottomNavBar)
    bottomNavBar.delegate = self
}

func bottomNavigationBar(_ bottomNavigationBar: MDCBottomNavigationBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem){
    guard let fromView = selectedViewController?.view, let toView = customizableViewControllers?[item.tag].view else {
        print(item.tag)
        return
    }

    if fromView != toView {
        UIView.transition(from: fromView, to: toView, duration: 0.3, options: [.transitionCrossDissolve], completion: nil)
    }
    self.selectedIndex = item.tag
}

func layoutBottomNavBar() {
    let size = bottomNavBar.sizeThatFits(view.bounds.size)
    var bottomNavBarFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.bounds.height - size.height, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    // Extend the Bottom Navigation to the bottom of the screen.
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        bottomNavBarFrame.size.height += view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
        bottomNavBarFrame.origin.y -= view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    }
    bottomNavBar.frame = bottomNavBarFrame
}
```

При нажатий Tab Bar выполняется "bottomNavigationBar didselect". Что нужно добавить чтобы экран менялся?

Comment: Напишите более развернутый вопрос.

Comment: Поправку сделал.

Comment: Вообще говоря tab bar в iOS как правило не требует программной генерации (хотя она и возможна), все делается в IB и очень просто. Я не знаком с material-design, это специфика их библиотеки?

Comment: Нашел решение! Надо было как раньше в swift-те создавать остальные экраны потом в Material Design добавлять. Вот маленький пример:

func setup_TabBar(){
        let one = UINavigationController(rootViewController: First_TB_ViewController())
        one.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "Home"), tag: 0)
        bottomNavBar.items = [ one.tabBarItem]
        viewControllers = [one]
        bottomNavBar.selectedItem = one.tabBarItem
        bottomNavBar.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(bottomNavBar)
        bottomNavBar.delegate = self 
}